# POWER QUERY APPEND date is missing

Tags: append, powerquery

I have two tables with similar columns
Apply append, all details were ok except for the date of the new table.
Old data dates are available, but the new one is missing and specified as "null"

I check their format, both are the same

Anyone once knows what is the issue. 
Below screenshot for reference

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L96VH.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's look like new table has different column name for date.